# How can I jailbreak my iPad 2?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

I want to jailbreak my iPad 2.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

What is your iPad firmware?
If you're running 4.3.3 you can use http://jailbreakme.com.